# What are plausible values for the Exhaust Gas Pressure Sensor?

Tags: hyundai, diesel-particulate-filter, i30

My car (a Hyundai i30 1.6 crdi form 2009) suffers from a dirty DPF. The errors I get are P1405 (Permanent Regeneration) and P2002 (Diesel Particulate Filter Efficiency Below Threshold). I know that these are measured by the Exhaust Gas Pressure Sensor (or DPFE (Differential Pressure Feedback Electronic)).

I can measure some sensors in my car with the Torque app on Android, together with a bluetooth dongle. However, unfortunatly this sensor was not supported. So I performed a 'scan' with Torque, and by detaching and attaching the sensor, I could find the PID. Now I can read the raw values. It's a single byte, so I *assume* that the values can range from 0-255 and that this *probably* corresponds to a voltage of 0-5V. And this voltage will correspond to some differential pressure (in mbar or hPa or PSI). But I don't know the formula.

I see that the raw value is around 50 at idle, and it raises when I rev up the engine. Before it could reach above 100. Then recently I used a DPF cleaner product and now the raw value only reaches to about 60.

However, the errors I mentioned earlier still occur. So probably this is still not good enough.

Now I would like to know what is a plausible value for this sensor. I assume a little raise in pressure is ok when the engine rpm raises, right? But how much?
What is a plausible pressure difference (measured in either pressure or voltage) when the DPF is clean? How can I tell it is good enough?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but one way to learn a plausible value is to find someone in your area who owns the same model and does not have a clogged DPF, plug your dongle into their car and read their PID. Or you could buy a short-term subscription to a repair data service such as Alldata DIY and access their diagnostic tree for the error codes you mentioned. They sometimes have data like "the PID should be between X and Y."